# Return type 'System.String' is not supported. Parameter name: expression MVC Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I am trying to create dropdown list from Enum in Asp.net MVC. With the below posted code, I am getting above error.

Here is code:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.SenderType, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SenderType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "SenderId,SenderName,SenderType,SenderPurpose,UserId")] SenderModel senderModel)
    {
        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                senderModel.UserId = int.Parse(currentUserId);

                db.Sender.Add(senderModel);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException /* dex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View(senderModel);
    }
```

Model:

```
public enum SenderType
{
    Transactional,
    Promotional
}
public class SenderModel
{
    [Key]
    public int SenderId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sender Name")]
    public string SenderName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Sender Type")]
    public string SenderType { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Sender Purpose")]
    public string SenderPurpose { get; set;}

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

I have posted my code. Help would be appreciated

Comment: What is model.SenderType?

Comment: You can see "public string SenderType { get; set; } " as string type in your model which EnumDropDownListFor does not support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have `SenderType` property as string type in your model which has been used in your razor, which is not supported by `EnumDropDownListFor` . `EnumDropDownListFor` expect enum type property so your `SenderType` property should be of type `SenderType` enum. So, your model should be :

```
public class SenderModel
{
    [Key]
    public int SenderId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sender Name")]
    public string SenderName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sender Type")]
    public SenderType SenderType { get; set; } // SenderType should be of type enum SenderType
    [Display(Name = "Sender Purpose")]
    public string SenderPurpose { get; set;}

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```